# How can i use data from antoher tables in a active record where in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

im trying to make a search form in a table that contains two ids as values, one of them is the id of an user and the other is the id of a project.
Here is my database schema:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.float    "lastLatitude"
    t.float    "lastLongitude"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.integer  "swipes"
    t.string   "profile_image"
 end

 create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.text     "bio"
   t.integer  "user_id"
   t.string   "salary"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   t.integer  "likes"
   t.string   "image"
   t.float    "latitude"
   t.float    "longitude"
 end

 create_table "matches", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "project_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

What i want to do is to create a search form in the matches index view to filter the matches by the user name or the project name, but i don't know how to do it, this is what i have right now:

```
 def self.search(search)
   if search
   where('User(user_id).name LIKE :search OR Project.name LIKE :search', search: "%#{search}%")
 else
   where(nil)
  end
end
```

Is it possible to do that?
 Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a scope approach

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

  scope name, ->(n) {
    joins(:user, :project).where("users.name like ? or projects.name like ? ", "%#{n}%", "%#{n}%")
  }
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  scope :name, ->(n) {
    where("users.name like ?", "%n%")
  }
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :name, ->(n) {
    where("projects.name like ?", "%n%")
  }
end
```

Comment: ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments). Using `where('users.name like :pat or projects.name like :pat', :pat => "%#{n}%")` might be better for the first one, less repetition and less noisy punctuation.

Comment: Thank you too, I'll change it